# Cross reference to different workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have two Excel files:

**File1**

> ```
>          A                B
> 1   NameofDeal  
> 2   Nike Man  
> 3   Nike Woman  
> 4   Adidas Man  
> 5   Adidas Woman
> ```

with many more rows, and other columns that are not here relevant.

**File2**

> ```
>       A             B           C         D  
> 1   NameofDeal    Company     TaxNo  
> 2   NIKE woman    Nike        101  
> 3   NIKE man      NIKE        101  
> 4   Adidas man    ADIDAS      102  
> 5   Reebok shorts Reebok      103  
> 6   Nike shoes    Nike        101
> ```

and other rows (but fewer than in File1) and columns that are not here relevant. Whether man or woman, the company may be the same. The Tax number is the same for Nike man and Nike woman and the same for Adidas man or Adidas woman, etc.

How do I achieve the likes of the following for the first workbook?

```
       A             B             C
1   NameofDeal    TaxNo
2   Nike Man       101
3   Nike Woman     101
4   Adidas Man     102
5   Adidas Woman   102
6   Reebok shorts  103
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> =VLOOKUP(A2,'~\Two.xlsx'!TList,3,0)

should suit, provided file Two is not in use ("locked"). `~` above is a place marker for the full  path and should be replaced to suit along the lines of D:\Folder1\Folder2    Care should be taken with apostrophes and final backslash.

The formula would be entered to the right of ColumnA and on the row for the first entry (here Row2), then copied down as far as required.

[image: SU14360370 example]

Note that the image does not show the full path because the files were open in the same Excel instance at the time the screenshot was taken.